# Do I need a resistor in a circuit of 80 LEDs in series for decoration?

Tags: power-supply, led, dc, white

Can I connect 80 LEDs of 3 V each in series to a source of 220 V without using a resistor? Will it have impact on the LEDs if I run them for 24 hours?

Comment: 220 V AC? My magic ball senses a bright flash followed by sparks and smoke.

Comment: You will need a resistor regardless.

Comment: This cannot be done.  Well it could be constructed... then Winny's comment would happen.  Irregardless of the (unlimited) forward current, the reverse voltage will destroy each LED in sequence (likely all of them within a few milliseconds.)

Comment: Don't mess around with mains electricity unless you've got enough training. If you're asking a question like this on SE, you don't have enough training. I know that sounds a little gatekeepy, but we're talking about something that can cause fires and kill you. Mess around with 12V all you want, don't mess with mains power.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the diodes are ideal.

3V for each diode and 80 diodes is 240V.

220V mains is a sine wave with peak voltage of 311V.

Without a resistor, the LEDs are off and no current flows until sine wave rises to 240V, and then LEDs start to conduct and as soon as voltage rises above 240V without resistor infinite current will flow.

In real life, something will likey spark, arc and flash within 10ms of connecting power. Literally a blink of an eye. You have no time to observe any long-term effects.

Please don't work on mains unless you can gather enough experience to make mains circuits, and it might still be dangerous if you don't know local electrical code and safety rules. And remember you are legally responsible for electrical devices and appliances you make, and in some countries, you may not be allowed to make them without having a degree/certificate. In some countries, the most complex electrical device you are allowed to make is an extension cord.

Comment: Just to be clear, LEDs do not suddenly conduct infinite current when a voltage greater than their minimum forward voltage is applied. But an LED that starts to glow at 3.0 V may reach rated current at 3.1 V and might withstand 3.2 V for a short time. I realize you used ideal diodes for your answer, but it's important to understand real characteristics.

Comment: @PStechPaul The actual or ideal behaviour does not matter in this case. So what if LEDs burst into flames at 240V or 256V, the actual forward voltages will vary due to tolerance etc anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The china manufacturers have been doing this for many years for the christmas season calling them fairy lights. That little blinker module can be replaced with a bridge rectifier. You would need a maximum of one resistor per string or put two strings in series each polarized in opposite directions on AC. I have seen where they put enough LEDs in series they do not use a resistor. When you place the LEDs in series the forward voltages add as do the reverse voltages. Usually the reverse voltage is much higher than the forward voltage. This can be verified by checking the data sheet. You can purchase these from your favorite china supplier for not very much, generally less than what you would pay for just the LEDs and they come assembled in both 120 and 240 volt ranges. I run them for about two months every Christmas season.

Comment: When they put enough LEDs in series they do not use a resistor. But they use the resistance of the cable and the rectifier instead. They may use a cable with extra thin wire or an alloy with more resistance than pure copper to get enough resistance. If they would use thick wires of pure copper without a resistor, the LEDs will be destroyed very soon, especially if there is some extra volts above nominal voltage. If you don't see a resistor there are hidden ones of course, hidden in the used cable.